# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' (how to remove this error)

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter, css-float, variable-assignment

TEXT PREPROCESSING

```
reviews=[comment.strip() for comment in reviews.comment] # remove both the leading and the trailing characters
reviews=[comment for comment in reviews if comment] # removes empty strings, because they are considered in Python as False
reviews[0:10]
```

OUTPUT :

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

> when i am trying to execute this code in jupyter below error is showing , anyone who knws how to solve. removing the float or strip also shows error.

the original output should show the reviews by customers.

Comment: Well, without knowing what the contents of comment is, you could force it to be a string, like so: `str(comment).strip()`

Comment: The way you fix this is to restrict use of *strip()* to string objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that in your notebook `reviews.comment` is a `list`, but it apparently contains not only strings but also floats. This immediately produces the error you see.

Maybe first check why there is a float in your `review.comment` and make sure it is there for a good reason and not already in error.

Furthermore, if the float is OK just convert it to a string:

```
reviews=[str(comment).strip() for comment in reviews.comment] # remove both the leading and the trailing characters
```